# Zend Framework: When to use /library or /application

Tags: zend-framework

after starting with zend framework for sometime, i started to think which classes shld be put where, in the `/library` or `/application`?

i think that reusable classes shld go to `/library` and application specific to `/application`? am i correct?

1 thing that i find more troublesome when using `/application` is that its not in the include path and i need to create a resource loader for it? eg.

```
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
    'namespace' => 'Application_',
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__)
));
$resourceLoader->addResourceType('validator', 'validators/', 'Validator');
$resourceLoader->addResourceType('acl', 'acl/', 'Acl');
```

Comment: the index.php is generated by zend_tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right!

/Library for more generic classes. Like the ones of Zend Framework, and /Application for application specific classes.

And yes, you need to register namespaces and add resources. So that Zend Autoloader can look inside these folders and require than. If all folders were automatically registered, the autoloader could load more slowly.